Docker driver "overlay2" failed to remove root filesystem: unlinkat read-only file system using windows powershell
I am using a Windows Powershell at Windows 11. I try to create an ubuntu 20.04 SDK manager image for a Qualcomm Roboplatform RB5 and failed.
Now I want to delete the 2dc4364a218c container.
> docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND               CREATED       STATUS       PORTS     NAMES
2dc4364a218c   ubuntu:20.04-sdkmanager   "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"   3 hours ago   Up 3 hours   22/tcp    sdkmanager_container

> docker rm 2dc4364a218c
Error response from daemon: container 2dc4364a218c20fb68a73adff03b28c3500245b7c0af70c3e8ab20e8d955dab0: driver "overlay2" failed to remove root filesystem: unlinkat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c6df829aaef9cc90b7cc5076f958a5bcd3f9d8d864d4811a19532774dc1b1aec: read-only file system

I try to use command:
> docker image prune


I also try using Docker for Windows

Both attemps give the same error message as follows:
(HTTP code 500) server error - container 2dc4364a218c20fb68a73adff03b28c3500245b7c0af70c3e8ab20e8d955dab0: driver "overlay2" failed to remove root filesystem: unlinkat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c6df829aaef9cc90b7cc5076f958a5bcd3f9d8d864d4811a19532774dc1b1aec: read-only file system

How to remove the container? Thank you very much in advance.
Warmest regards,
Suryadi

The most obvious thing I see is that the container is running.  If you docker stop sdkmanager_container, can you then docker rm it successfully?

I do stop the sdkmanager_container. As in windows docker picture, the sdkmanager_container in stop condition. However, I still can not docker rm the container. Thank you.
